# Hibernate is not getting Inherited attributes in parent class of pojo

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, annotations, pojo

I have some common fields in every table of `Database`

**added_on** and **added_by**

> I created a pojo class:

```
public class CommonBean{

    @Column(name="added_on")
    public Date addedOn;

    @Column(name="added_by")
    public Integer addedBy;

    //setters and getters
}
```

And all the `pojo` classes are `extends` that `pojo` class:

example:

```
@Table(name = "employee")
@Entity
public class HrEmployee extends CommonBean implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

But When I am calling list method of hibernate criteria.
I can see the generated query in the console:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* criteria query */ select
        this_.id as y0_,
        this_.first_name as y2_,
        this_.middle_name as y3_,
        this_.last_name as y4_ 
    from
        hr_employee this_
```

Why it is not getting attributes from its parent class?

I am not sure whether it is possible or I am making mistake somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: Try entity inheritance - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate CommonBean class with @MappedSuperclass annotation

Answer (score 0):

You need to Annotate Super class with @MappedSuperclass. this is how you say hibernate to inherit properties from super class
[this will help you](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)